# Extern page with Tornado web server

Tags: import, handler, tornado

I have an handler in a Python page written following the guide lines of the Tornado web server. I would to bring this handler in an other page, always linked with the main python page of Tornado.

In that way can I create a new page so I can have a nice project and not an unique page of thousand of lines?

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you talk about handlers then use object inherit NewHandler(OldHandler)

Comment: But all the initial configurations? I write only the new handler in the external page??

Comment: do you mean multi domain using tornado (exemple1.com exemple2.com with the same tornado instance)?

Comment: No I mean the same instance that call an handler in Tornado and this handler is in another page, not in the primary page of Tornado where I put all the define, import and the class Application... sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.removeslash
    def get_current_user(self):
         return self.get_secure_cookie("mechtari")
    @property 
    def db(self):
        if not hasattr(BaseHandler,"_db"):
            _db = pymongo.Connection().essog
            return _db
    @property
    def fs(self):
        if not hasattr(BaseHandler,"_fs"):
            _fs = gridfs.GridFS(self.db)
            return _fs
```

**now all what i'll do will inherit from this handler:**

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
    # do a database search, so i need to connect to database, so no need to the database everytime and make the connection.


class AchatsHandler(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    def get(self):
        # render me a page that requires a user to be authentificated, so i always use the base handler
```

and in the url specs, you only precise the name of classes to bind them to urls.

```
urls = [
(r"/login", handlers.LoginHandler),
(r"/achats/*", handlers.AchatsHandler),
]
```

**and see, there is no BaseHandler in the url dictionnary!**

Comment: it is the Object Oriented Programming Inheritence:
http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/
this is espetially useful to not repeat codes :p